# Drop list of Column from a single dataframe in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a `Dataframe` resulting from a join of two `Dataframe`s: `df1` and `df2` into `df3`. All the columns found in `df2` are also in `df1`, **but their contents differ**. I'd like to remove all the `df1` columns which names are in `df2.columns` from the join. Would there be a way to do this without using a var?
Currently I've done this

```
var ret = df3
df2.columns.foreach(coln => ret = ret.drop(df2(coln)))
```

but what I really want is just a shortcut for

```
df3.drop(df1(df2.columns(1))).drop(df1(df2.columns(2)))....
```

without using a var.

Passing a list of columns is not an option, don't know if it's because I'm using spark 2.2

**EDIT:**

Important note: I don't know in advance the columns of `df1` and `df2`

Comment: Did you try specify the join column as an array type or string? https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/faq/join-two-dataframes-duplicated-column.html

Comment: @KZapagol thanks but that's not what I need, columns with the same name contain different values, that's why I need to remove only the one from the first dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shortcut would be:

```
val ret  = df2.columns.foldLeft(df3)((acc,coln) => acc.drop(df2(coln)))
```

I would suggest to remove the columns before the join. Alternatively, select only the columns from df3 which come from df2:

```
val ret = df3.select(df2.columns.map(col):_*)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is possible to achieve while you are performing the join itself. Please try the below code

```
 val resultDf=df1.alias("frstdf").join(broadcast(df2).alias("scndf"),  $"frstdf.col1" === $"scndf.col1", "left_outer").selectExpr("scndf.col1","scndf.col2"...)//.selectExpr("scndf.*")
```

This would only contain the columns from the second data frame. Hope this helps

Comment: My question is scala oriented - I need to know if there is a shortcut for applying a chain of transformations. Anyways this is a really good answer, I'll consider accepting this as the final answer if no other answer will be better.

Comment: Its written in Scala. Chain of Transformations is also possible within SelectExpr. You can concat, calculate , cast columns very easily.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but as I specified in my edit, I don't know in advance the columns of the two dataframes in input